# Iterate each folder in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

In our DataLake storage, we received unspecified amount of folders every day. Each of these folders contain at least one file.

```
Example of folders:

    FolderA

    |_/2020

       |_/03

          |_/12

              |_fileA.json

        |_/04

           |_/13

               |_fileB.json

    FolderB

    |_/2020

       |_/03

          |_/12

              |_fileC.json
Folder C/...
Folder D/...
So on..
```

Now:
1. How do I iterate every folders and get the file(s) inside it?

2. I would also like to do 'Copy Data' from each of these files and make a single .csv file from it. What would be the best approach to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single copy activity using wildcard filtering in the source dataset, as seen here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/data-factory-supports-wildcard-file-filter-for-copy-activity/

Then in the sink tab of the copy activity, select Merge Files in the Copy behavior as seen here:

[image: Merge files]

If you have extra requirements, another way to do this is by using Mapping Dataflows. Mark Kromer explains a similar scenario here: https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/07/05/adf-mapping-data-flows-iterate-multiple-files-with-source-transformation/

Hope this helped!